# Access value in OleDbDataApter

Tags: c#

Using `OleDbDataAdapter` SQL query to search for secific entry in [access](/questions/tagged/access) database.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT Gallery_Number  FROM Paintings WHERE Painting Number = '" + searchString + "'", myDB);
searchString = Convert.ToString( adapter);
```

`searchString` returns `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter` and not a Gallery number. 
I would like to know how to get the value of this adapter and put it into a `textbox`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd use a [Scalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) for this, since you only return a single value.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Connection.Open();
int galeryNumber = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

But let's take a look at your code:

```
DataSet galNum = new DataSet();
oledbAdapter.Fill(galNum);
int galeryNumber = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

The best way to gain access to a `OleDbDataAdapter` is by converting the result set into a `DataSet. Then you can [iterate through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) this set.

```
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
      DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]; //One result line in your set
      //DataRow contains n columns
      for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
      {
         string someEntry = dr[i].ToString();
      }
}
```